# Is it possible to configure emqttc to use proxy Information

Tags: proxy, erlang, mqtt

Is it possible to use emqttc `https://github.com/emqtt/emqttc` when behind a proxy? 
You can pass SSL options to the `emqttc:start_link` function but it doesn't appear to do anything for a proxy. As an example I've tried using `{proxy_auth,{Proxy_Username, Proxy_Password}}`  as an option. Any suggestions on if this is possible or how to configure it for proxy use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use a HTTP proxy to forward native MQTT connections, they are 2 totally different protocols.

You could forward MQTT over Websockets, but it does not appear that emttc supports MQTT over Websockets.